# Dynamics CRM Copy Campaign Privilage

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics, copying, privilege

I'm working on a CRM project. My customers want to restrict some of campaign menu options. They particularly want to limit the copying of a campaign. I checked user roles but I can not find anything about it. So how can I take to privilege of copying campaign?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there isn't no specific security privilege to allow to copy a campaign (you can check the necessary security privileges [here](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e879bfbd-499f-4747-b9e2-729088d82363/required-security-settings-for-copy-as-campaigncopy-as-template-feature-in-mscrm)).

If changing those privileges is not an option, you can always edit the command bar using some tool like Ribbon Workbench and hide the Copy button (bear in mind that you would be hiding that functionality to all the users) or apply some custom enable rule. You can check how to to this [here](https://ribbonworkbench.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/102796-5-hiding-unhiding-ribbon-elements).